# Retrieve real world time from time saved using "Clock" → "To Workspace" in Simulink

Tags: simulation, simulink, simulator, data-acquisition

I have made some measurements with an NI6024 acquisition card using Simulink, with the following model:

[image]

I have run the simulation with simulation time = "inf" and a fixed time step of 0.2, in order to collect real time data from the card. But I didn't realize that the values that "Clock" gives do not correspond to real-world time. More specifically, I have run the experiment for about a minute but the data in the variable "t" range from 0 to about 50000, which is clearly wrong. I have saved the workspace data, and I have access to the recorded data (the variables "t" and "h"), but have no means to reproduce the experiment.

**Is there any way to retrieve the real world time of the simulation?**

Answer (score 1):

You've basically got two choices.

1. Run your model in real time, using for instance something like [Simulink Real-Time](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-real-time.html), or other real time OS.  In this case the (wall clock) time will represent time since the model was started.
2. Write an S-Function to *slow down* the simulation so that it *fakes* real time.  There are multiple examples of doing this on the File Exchange.  See [Real-Time Pacer for Simulink](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29107-real-time-pacer-for-simulink) for one such example.